# Is there a way to convert markdown to interpreted RTF?

Tags: python, markdown, clipboard, rtf, automator

I am trying to convert a text from markdown to rendered RTF in a shell script and wrap the command in an Apple Automator Service.

I realized that the only way to achieve the task is by doing:

```
python -m markdown | textutil -convert rtf -format html -stdin -stdout -font Helvetica -inputencoding UTF-8 | pbcopy | pbpaste -Prefer rtf
```

**Question**:

- How to avoid using the clipboard to interpret RTF?
- Is there another application to use instead of `pbcopy` `pbpaste`?

Cmd explain:

- `python -m markdown` does the main work
- `textutil [… opts]` converts from HTML to RTF
- `pbcopy | pbpaste -Prefer rtf` does the magic interpreting plain-text RTF directives out from `textutil` and returning as interpreted RTF.

The issue would be far easier if RTF were not requested to be interpreted. I already tried to call the first two steps of the pipe and able to save rtf-formatted files (and other formats as well) correctly.

Answer (score 10):

Did you take a look at [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/demos.html) ? This tool can convert Markdown files to RTF easily.

Usage:

```
pandoc -s INPUT.md -o OUTPUT.rtf
```

[EDIT]

If you want a full pythonic solution, you can use the package `pypandoc` which is a wrapper around the pandoc tool (thanks @rusty-shackleford for the comment)

Comment: Since this question was tagged for Python, it might be helpful for future searchers who land here to note that [pypandoc](https://pypi.org/project/pypandoc/) very conveniently wraps Pandoc.

Comment: you're right, i'll edit the response